# tkFileDialog won't open gui when running script from cmd

Tags: python, user-interface, file-io, cmd

I building a messenger with possibility to send files. Iv'e added this line to prevent the tk window to be shown:

```
Tk().withdraw()
```

and I'm opening files with this command

```
tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

through IDLE python editor it all seems to be working, but when I open python script through cmd and try to send a file , the gui do not show up at all, and the dialog to choose file doesn't open.

when I remove the command Tk().withdraw() , it seems to be working again , but this stupid blank Tk window is still shown up.

How do I prevent the blank Tk from being shown up when I running the script from cmd without causing the choose file dialog to disappear?

this is the code (I'm using python 2.7 , and this is not the whole code, I pasted just the necessary parts):

```
from Tkinter import Tk
import tkFileDialog

messege = raw_input()
if messege == "SEND":
    print "Starting to send file..."
    isSendingFile = True
    resDir = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    filetype = resDir[(resDir.rfind('.')):]
    filename = resDir[(resDir.rfind('/') + 1):-(len(filetype))]
    s.send("SEND|name:" + filename + "|type:" + filetype)
    fileToSend = open(resDir, "rb")
    messege = fileToSend.read()
    s.send(messege)
    fileToSend.close()
    isSendingFile = False
```

Comment: did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20822863/4279) help you in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to keep a reference to the main window:

```
import os

try: # Python 2
    from Tkinter import Tk
    from tkSimpleDialog import askstring
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() # hide main window

message = askstring("Message", "What is the message?")
if message == "SEND":
   resdir = askopenfilename()
   root.destroy() # done with gui
   path, filetype = os.path.splitext(resdir)
   filename = os.path.basename(path)
```